# Guava version (FluentIterable) - ошибка старта приложения

Tags: java, spring, maven, swagger

Ранее в зависимостях (использую maven с pom.xml) была зависимость на Guava с версией 15.0, подключил Swagger:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

и теперь при старте приложения (SpringBoot версия 2.2.5) оно падает с ошибкой:

```
An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.dependentModels(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:79)

The following method did not exist:
com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable.concat(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Ljava/lang/Iterable;)Lcom/google/common/collect/FluentIterable;

The method's class, com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/C:/Users/ME/.m2/repository/com/google/javascript/closure-compiler/v20151216/closure-compiler-v20151216.jar!/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/ME/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/21.0/guava-21.0.jar!/com/google/common/collect/FluentIterable.class

It was loaded from the following location:
file:/C:/Users/ME/.m2/repository/com/google/javascript/closure-compiler/v20151216/closure-compiler-v20151216.jar
```

Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable

Похожую проблему я нашел и решения на нее тоже (не помогли):

1. Сменил версию Guava на 20.0
2. Удалил локальный jar, выкачал заново
3. Удалил конфигурационный класс сваггера, заработало, но тогда у меня не будет сваггера))

Однако нашел ответ с использованием принудительной версии Guava на Gradle:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.guava:guava:$guavaVersion"
}
```

К сожалению, у меня Maven и пока я не нашел похожего функционала в нем.

**Вопрос** - как можно решить эту проблему? Или стоит переехать на третий сваггер и там оно все само-собой решится?

Answer (score 0):

**Решено:**
Помогло переехать на новую версию сваггера (2.10.5)

Не знаю насколько это хорошее решение, но работает. Думаю, наиболее лучшим будет переезд на версию 3.0.0

**upd**: по итогу сменил версию на 3.0.0